# How to correctly add Vaadin framework into my Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-spring-boot

I am trying to integrate what is done in this official Vaadin video tutorial (implement back end push notification) into my Spring Boot project.
I am finding some problem trying to understand how to correctly integrate Vaadin framework into my existing Spring Boot project **pom.xml** file in order to have all the dependencies needed to work.

So basically this is the video tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5sbGvW3S4I

and this is the related GitHub link of this tutorial example code: https://github.com/marcushellberg/fusion-push-notifications

This is the **pom.xml** of my already existing Spring Boot project where I need to insert Vaadin framework and the related example project dependencies (needed to implement the desired behavior)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.easydefi</groupId>
    <artifactId>GET-USER-WS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GET-USER-WS</name>
    <description>Microservice that retrieves users from DB</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        
        <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
          <version>1.68</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In particular this is the **pom.xml** content of the previous Vaadin example (from the Vaadin GitHub example project repo):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
  <artifactId>fusion-push-notifications</artifactId>
  <name>Project base for Spring Boot and Vaadin Flow</name>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <java.version>16</java.version>
    <vaadin.version>19.0.8</vaadin.version>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
  </parent>

  <repositories>
    <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

    <!-- Main Maven repository -->
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
      <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
    </repository>
    <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
    <repository>
      <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
      <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
      <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
      <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
      <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
      <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.68</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
        <configuration>
          <wait>500</wait>
          <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
      <id>production</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>compile</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <productionMode>true</productionMode>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>it</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>

          <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
              <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
</project>
```

I tried to adapt my original project **pom.xml** in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.easydefi</groupId>
    <artifactId>GET-USER-WS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GET-USER-WS</name>
    <description>Microservice that retrieves users from DB</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <repositories>
    <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
    
        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/</url>
        </repository>
        
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        
        <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
          <version>1.68</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- Vaadin and push request related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.68</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
          <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
     

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But it seems not work, I am obtaining a lot of error on this new version of my **pom.xml**

What am I missing? How can I try to correctly add Vaading framework to my original Spring Boot project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only real thing that is missing is the `vaadin.version`...

```xml
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>19.0.8</vaadin.version> <!-- missing -->
    </properties>
```

But you should avoid mixing spring versions, which sometimes can cause some problems.
Example: `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.5` and `spring-boot-starter-aop:2.6.3`